# How make python3x read terminal output from karma?

Tags: python

I make a script to works as laucher for karma and slimerjs.

It is like this:

```
    # Load a Karma server
        print('\nKarma is loading...\n')
        karma = subprocess.Popen('./karma start', shell=True)

        # delays for 2 seconds for waiting Karma server
        time.sleep(2)

        # Load a headless SlimerJS that points to Karma server
        slimerjs = subprocess.Popen(
            'xvfb-run slimerjs slimerjs-cfg.js > slimerjs.log', shell=True)
        print('\nSlimerJS is running...\n')
```

It works, but there is a big problem with this, the arbitrary delay of 2 seconds. I need it to only call the slimerjs after the karma is really loaded , that is why i use the delay.
But karma gives me an output on console like this:

```
18 02 2017 03:11:12.176:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/

18 02 2017 03:11:12.190:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
```

So, I can use this output to replace the arbitrary delay of 2 seconds, and I also need get the output to know WHERE the karma starts

I Need get the server path/location (http://localhost:9876/) to say the slimerjs where the karma is running.

I tryed some commands like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./karma start"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
```

But python give me an error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './karma start'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Without `shell=True` you need the `Popen` call to look like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./karma", "start"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

also to get the website:

```
location = p.stdout.split(' ')[-1]
```

If you are using python version >= 3.5, then you can use `subprocess.run` the newer, higher-level version of `Popen`. Docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).